# Use innerHTML, createElement, and plain Javascript to create music player dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

My player and code is here at codepen: https://codepen.io/peggysue/pen/YzyorvM. How the player works for now is a user will put the player HTML in the body. He will import the css and javascript files.
The HTML for the player is this:

```
<div id="audioPlayer">
 <div id="progress">
    <div class="filled-progress"></div>
 </div>
 <div id='bottom-wrapper'>
  <div id='song-timer'>
     <span class="current-time"></span>
     <span>/</span>
     <span class="duration"></span>
  </div>
  <div id='loopButton'></div>
  <div id='volumeWrap'>
   <div id='volumeMute'></div>
    <div id='volumePanel'>
     <div id='volumeSlider'>
      <div id='volume-slider-track'>
       <div id='volumeProgress'>
        <div id='volume-slider-handle'></div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I'm trying to bring the player in dynamically for the user who cannot code. I want to use innerHTML instead of creating elements, setting attributes, appending, and prepending for the user who can code minimally and would like to rearrange the player and style it how he prefers.

And If he's not code-savvy, he can just add the css and javascript files and the player will do everything for itself (after I've enabled the player to see if a file is a playable audiofile and set an `src` attribute). I've tried to recreate the player using this code:

```
var audio = document.createElement('audio');
var audioPlayer = document.createElement('div');
audioPlayer.setAttribute('id', 'audioPlayer');
audioPlayer.innerHTML = [
      '  <div id='progress'>',
      '     <div class='filled-progress'></div>',
      '  </div>',
      '  <div id='bottom-wrapper'>',
      '     <div id='song-timer'>',
      '         <span>/</span>',
      '         <span class='duration'></span>',
      '     </div>',
      '     <div id='loopButton'></div>',
      '  <div id='volumeWrap'>',
      '   <div id='volumeMute'></div>',
      '    <div id='volumePanel'>',
      '     <div id='volumeSlider'>',
      '      <div id='volume-slider-track'>',
      '       <div id='volumeProgress'>',
      '        <div id='volume-slider-handle'></div>',
      '      </div>',
      '     </div>',
      '    </div>',
      '   </div>',
      '  </div>',
      ' </div>'].join('');

document.body.appendChild(audioPlayer);
```

In the javascript is this code that will follow and have to be altered:

```
var audio = document.createElement('audio');
var audioPlayer = document.getElementById('audioPlayer'); // audioPlayer
var loopButton = document.getElementById('loopButton'); // loop button
var progress = document.getElementById('progress');
var progressFilled = document.querySelector('.filled-progress');
```

I've tried deleting the `var audioPlayer = document.getElementById('audioPlayer');` and substituting it with my code, to no avail. I've searched the internet and not been able to make a go of anything.

Comment: `'  <div id='progress'>',` you have single quotes in your HTML.  syntax error.  string`' <div id='` variable: `progress` string:`'>'`,  you should use backticks for template string syntax ` so you don't have to do all that escaping or use that join there.

Comment: This worked. Thanks so much!

Comment: you may want to look into templates

Comment: @The Fool: Great! I looked and see that templates will speed up processes because they don't send HTTP requests to the server and so are lightning fast. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have single quotes in your HTML. Causing a syntax error.  string: `' <div id='` variable: `progress` string `:'>'`.  You should use backticks ` for template string syntax, so you don't have to do all that escaping or use that join there.

```
audioPlayer.innerHTML =`  <div id='progress'>
     <div class='filled-progress'></div>
  </div>
  <div id='bottom-wrapper'>
     <div id='song-timer'>
         <span>/</span>
         <span class='duration'></span>
     </div>
     <div id='loopButton'></div>
  <div id='volumeWrap'>
   <div id='volumeMute'></div>
    <div id='volumePanel'>
     <div id='volumeSlider'>
      <div id='volume-slider-track'>
       <div id='volumeProgress'>
        <div id='volume-slider-handle'></div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>`;
```

Comment: ah, I'm guessing you used backticks for each line and then `join`ed it in the end?  don't worry about pasting it in

Comment: @ user 120242:  I did it like you, but added: `<div id='audioPlayer'></div>` and got rid of `audioPlayer.setAttribute('id', 'audioPlayer')`. No joining needed.

Comment: This worked great in Chrome, Firefox, Brave, and Edge, but not in IE. To work in IE, I transpiled the template string syntax to ES5 that IE supports. I transpiled the syntax using BABEL: https://babeljs.io/repl/